# Convert Stored Proc Call using OO4O to ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, vb.net, stored-procedures, odp.net

I'm fairly new to VB.NET and Oracle. I'm currently trying to convert functions which call stored procedures using OO4O types to one that uses ODP.NET as part of a maintenance effort to do away with obsolete references.

I think my issue lies with the 3 ".AddTable" commands.
On the Oracle side these parameters are defined as "TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)       INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER".
I don't have access to the Oracle side or any more information about the stored proc as it is handled by a third party. Both the function snippets are below.

Any advice would be appreciated!

`Working Function Using OO4O`

```
        Dim oraParams As OracleInProcServer.OraParameters

        'Return parameters
        oraParams.Add("NUMBER", -1, pmORAPARM_OUTPUT, vbLong)

        'Pass parameters to the stored procedure.
        oraParams.Add("a_st", strA_st, pmORAPARM_INPUT, vbString)
        oraParams.Add("a_st_version", strA_st_version, pmORAPARM_BOTH)
        oraParams.Add("a_sc", strA_sc, pmORAPARM_BOTH, vbString)
        oraParams.Add("a_ref_date", objA_ref_date, pmORAPARM_INPUT, ORATYPE_DATE)
        oraParams.Add("a_create_ic", strA_create_ic, pmORAPARM_INPUT, vbString)
        oraParams.Add("a_create_pg", strA_create_pg, pmORAPARM_INPUT, vbString)
        oraParams.Add("a_userid", strA_userid, pmORAPARM_INPUT, vbString)
        oraParams.AddTable("a_fieldtype_tab", pmORAPARM_INPUT, ORATYPE_VARCHAR2, 1, 20)
        oraParams.AddTable("a_fieldnames_tab", pmORAPARM_INPUT, ORATYPE_VARCHAR2, 1, 20)
        oraParams.AddTable("a_fieldvalues_tab", pmORAPARM_INPUT, ORATYPE_VARCHAR2, 1, 40)
        oraParams.Add("a_nr_of_rows", iA_nr_of_rows, pmORAPARM_INPUT, vbLong)
        oraParams.Add("a_modify_reason", strA_modify_reason, pmORAPARM_INPUT, vbString)

        g_cOraDatabase.SQL_Execute("Begin :NUMBER:=UNAPISC.CreateSam(:a_st, :a_st_version, :a_sc, :a_ref_date, :a_create_ic, :a_create_pg, :a_userid, :a_fieldtype_tab, :a_fieldnames_tab, :a_fieldvalues_tab, :a_nr_of_rows, :a_modify_reason);commit;end;")
```

`New Function Using ODP.NET`

```
    Dim strA_fieldtype_tab As String()
    Dim strA_fieldnames_tab As String()
    Dim strA_fieldvalues_tab As String()
    Dim testOraCMD As New OracleCommand
    Dim testCon As New OracleConnection

    'DB and Stored Proc Settings
    testCon.ConnectionString = "user id=" & g_strDBUser & ";password=" & g_strDBPassword & ";data source=" & g_strDBDatabase & ";"

    testCon.Open()
    testOraCMD.Connection = testCon
    testOraCMD.CommandText = "UNAPISC.CreateSam"
    testOraCMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

    'Return parameters
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("NUMBER", OracleDbType.Long)).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

    'Pass parameters to the stored procedure.
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_ST", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = strST
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_ST_VERSION", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.InputOutput)).Value = strA_st_version
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_SC", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.InputOutput)).Value = strA_sc
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_REF_DATE", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = objA_ref_date
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_CREATE_IC", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = strA_create_ic
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_CREATE_PG", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = strA_create_pg
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_USERID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = strA_userid

    Dim f_type As OracleParameter
    f_type = testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_FIELDTYPE_TAB", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input))
    f_type.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    f_type.Value = strA_fieldtype_tab
    f_type.Size = strA_fieldtype_tab.Length

    Dim f_name As OracleParameter
    f_name = testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_FIELDNAMES_TAB", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input))
    f_name.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    f_name.Value = strA_fieldnames_tab
    f_name.Size = strA_fieldnames_tab.Length

    Dim f_values As OracleParameter
    f_values = testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_FIELDVALUES_TAB", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input))
    f_values.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    f_values.Value = strA_fieldvalues_tab
    f_values.Size = strA_fieldvalues_tab.Length

    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_NR_OF_ROWS", OracleDbType.Long, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = iA_nr_of_rows
    testOraCMD.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("A_MODIFY_REASON", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = strA_modify_reason

    'Call Stored Proc
    testOraCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Clean up
    testCon.Close()
    testCon.Dispose()
    testOraCMD.Dispose()
```

If I don't assign a value to the 3 arrays (As no value is assigned in the original working function), I get the message "OracleParameter.Value is invalid". If I assign any single character/ string/ character array/ string array, I receive: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" & vbLf & "ORA-06512: at line 1"

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: In the second code you don't specify any procedure call, just the parameters. That could  be key item.

Comment: This is defined higher up in the function. I've added this part to the snippet to avoid confusion. The DB connection and stored proc identification is successful. It's the parameters "types" that returns an error

Comment: Check carefully the signature of the function and the values.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful:  [Tip: ODP.NET does not require tnsnames.ora](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/220912/tip-odp-net-does-not-require-tnsnames-ora) and [Using ODP.NET without tnsnames.ora using Oracles OracleConnection](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/using-odpnet-without-tnsnamesora/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
testOraCMD.CommandText = "UNAPISC.CreateSam"
testOraCMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

you may try

```
testOraCMD.CommandText = "Begin :NUMBER := UNAPISC.CreateSam(:a_st, :a_st_version, :a_sc, :a_ref_date, :a_create_ic, :a_create_pg, :a_userid, :a_fieldtype_tab, :a_fieldnames_tab, :a_fieldvalues_tab, :a_nr_of_rows, :a_modify_reason);end;"
testOraCMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
```

AssociativeArray parameters are added like this:

```
Dim chngId As Long()
par = testOraCMD.Parameters.Add("chngId", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Input)
par.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
par.Value = chngId
par.Size = chngId.Length
```

Comment: I tried this. It does not work. I've found out that the 3 parameters ending with "tab" are defined on the Oracle side as "TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER". 
I think I need to add "OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray" to these parameters, but I still can't get it to work. 
The existing function has no values assigned - If I don't assign a value I get the message "OracleParameter.Value is invalid".
If I assign any character/string/character array I receive: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" & vbLf & "ORA-06512: at line 1"

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I've edited my original post to include the test code for adding the parameters as Associative Arrays, as well as the error messages it returns. Any ideas?